# Service discovery in fabric-java-sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running Service discovery to invoke a transaction. I am getting this error. I am using fabric-sdk-java v1.4.0.

I have set `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT as peer_name:port`

```
Chaincode.org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ServiceDiscoveryException: Failed to find and endorsers for chaincode fabcar.
```

Also in the grpc logs, I am repeatedly getting the below warning.

```
WARNING: [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl-965] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=NameResolver returned an empty list, cause=null}
Mar 01, 2019 11:37:51 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl onError
```

fabric-sdk-java logs

```
[pool-5-thread-1] INFO org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery - Channel mychannel doing discovery with peer: Peer{ id: 3, name: pr1, channelName: mychannel, url: grpc://10.80.102.129:8051}
[pool-5-thread-1] ERROR org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery - Error failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"fabcar" > 
[pool-5-thread-1] WARN org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ServiceDiscovery - Channel mychannel failed to find all layouts for chaincodes. Expected: 1 and found: 0
[grpc-default-executor-21] WARN org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.PeerEventServiceClient - Received error on  PeerEventServiceClient{id: 8360, channel: mychannel, peerName: pr1:7051, url: grpc://pr1:7051}, attempts 8351. UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host pr1
[grpc-default-executor-21] WARN org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.PeerEventServiceClient - Received error on  PeerEventServiceClient{id: 8410, channel: mychannel, peerName: pr1:7051, url: grpc://pr1:7051}, attempts 8401. UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host pr1
```

What could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your peer to your `/etc/hosts/` file.

In your case, I believe that you should add the following line:

`10.80.102.129  pr1`